Browsershot can't find node command even though it is installed and in the path on Windows
I am trying to create PDF's with Spatie Browsershots,
$html = view('components.pages.student.result.check', [
    'results' => $results, 
    'average' => $average, 
    'student' => $student])->render();

$pdf = Browsershot::html($html)->pdf();

return new Response($pdf, 200, [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="result.pdf"'
]);

but keep getting this error

The command "node "C:\Users\HP\Documents\GitHub\School_Management_app\vendor\spatie\browsershot\src/../bin/browser.cjs" "{""url"":""file://C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\1925459280-0381687001715740509\index.html"",""action"":""pdf"",""options"":{""args"":[],""viewport"":{""width"":800,""height"":600},""displayHeaderFooter"":false}}"" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: C:\Users\HP\Documents\GitHub\School_Management_app\public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

**Ive check and yes, Node is install, The pc env path points to the node .exe,
I've also check other people with same error and their way of fixing didn't work.
My error is
================

Error Output:
================ 'node'

and theirs is
================

Error Output:
================ 'sh'


Did you get any success with this? If Condor's answer helped you, would be nice to say so, and possibly mark it as correct.

Judging by the directory paths from the error, you are using Windows. As far as I remember, there is such a problem in Browsershot, it is usually solved by setting the PATH environment variable, you need to specify the correct path to the installed NodeJs. Or write the path directly in the code, for example:
Browsershot::html($html)
->setNodeBinary('C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe')
->setNpmBinary('C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm')
->pdf();

